# MySql server PID not found

Tags: mysql, linux, nginx

I have CentOS 6.4 with NGINX.

When I try to `start/stop/restart` mysql server `(/etc/init.d/mysqld restart)` I get this error:

```
MySQL server PID file could not be found!                  [FAILED]
Starting MySQL..The server quit without updating PID file ([FAILED]/mysql/mysqld.pid).
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at your init script and check the path/permission of the PID file.

Comment: First check mysql error log to see what happened: `less /var/log/mysql/error.log` and scroll down to bottom or Shift+g

Comment: /var/log/mysql/error.log: No such file or directory

Comment: @mirkobrankovic Thank you for providing me informations, but error.log does not exists

Comment: was mysql-server ever started on that server? check `/var/log/mysql.err` maybe it's writing in that file

Comment: default location of the mysql error log is within your mysql-home, most likely /var/lib/mysql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same error on a CentOS 6.3 where I upgraded MySQL to 5.6.14 but I kept the old my.cnf file. After upgrade, MySQL did not start anymore, giving me the same error as you described.

The problem was that I had this setting in my.cnf:

```
table_cache=2048
```

According to this link [table_cache renamed table_open_cache](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68315)..

> "Seem like in 5.5 the system variable table_cache was renamed
>   table_open_cache.. 
>   In 5.6 mysqld fails if it finds an unknown variable
>   this means that upgrades from versions earlier than 5.5 can have
>   problems if table_cache is specified in my.cnf."

After I changed the above line to

```
table_open_cache=2048
```

MySQL started perfectly.

So, in the case you have MySQL 5.5+ (and maybe an older my.cnf), I suggest you to do the following:

- remove my.cnf from /etc folder and try to start MySQL
- if MySQL starts, the the problem is in my.cnf. Comment/uncomment all the settings one by one in order to see which is causing the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Asking questions inside answer is not fair.

Comment: @Vinod VT, it's my first post on stackoverflow so Im not yet familiar with the rules. I will delete the questions if this is the right way to post an answer.

Comment: This was exactly the same problem for me upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I upgraded my Mac OS to 10.9.3 and encountered the above problem on mysql.server restart

The following fixed my problem

```
sudo chmod -R o+rwx /usr/local/var/mysql/
sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/var/mysql/
sudo mysql.server restart
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/CRMPiccosMacBook.pid)`

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that which folder/file is not exist in /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

if dir not exists then create it as:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld/
```

if mysqld.pid is not exists then create it as:

```
sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

change ownership as:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/run/mysqld
chmod 775 -R /var/run/mysqld
```

restart mysql service

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that sometimes MySQL processes are still running.  Certainly this was the case on my OS X Yosemite system so use the following command to find any processes that show up with MySQL in the name:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Then kill them using the command 
`sudo kill -9 PID`, replacing `PID` with the offending process ID.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a lock.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql status
```

If the OS says that there is a lock, something like:

```
ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists
```

remove that lock file and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked....

```
# ps aux | grep mysql
root      3668  0.0  0.0  11432  1240 ?        S     2014   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/db/data01 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
mysql     5303  0.1  0.4 1964748 12368 ?       S<l   2014 1663:35 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/db/data01 --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/db/logs01/mysql-error.err --open-files-limit=8192 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306
root     12369  0.0  0.0   6376   680 pts/0    S+   09:05   0:00 grep mysql
# kill -9 3668 5303
# rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql rm: remove regular empty file `/var/lock/subsys/mysql'? y
# service mysql start Starting MySQL (Percona Server).. SUCCESS!
```